# ClipPath with setLayerType as Software crashes

Tags: java, android

I am trying to clip a path in my custom view but it appears black in color. Through searching and finding the reason for same. Found that I need to set " `setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE,null)`". After this it appears perfect but crashes in some deivices.

Crash Log(One of these based on devices):

1. java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
2. Bitmap exceeds 32bit

   ```
   public class CardLayout extends LinearLayout {

   private View mRoot;
   private ImageView mCategoryImageView;
   private LinearLayout mCategoryBottomView;

   private RectF mRect;
   private Paint mPaint;
   private View mDivider;
   private Path mPath;
   private int mPadding = 30;

   public CardLayout(Context context) {
       super(context);
   }

   public CardLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
       super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
   }

   public CardLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
       mContext = context;
       mRoot = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_content, null);
       addView(mRoot);
       initUI();
   }

   private void initUI() {

       mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
       mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
       mPath = new Path();

       mCategoryHeadlineTextView = (TextView) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.categoryHeadline);
       mCategoryImageView = (ImageView) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.categoryImageView);
       mCategoryBottomView = (LinearLayout) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.ctg_btm_view);
       mDivider = mRoot.findViewById(R.id.divider);

       setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE,null);
   }

   public void setCategoryImage(String categoryUrl) {
       if (mCategoryImageView != null) {
           Glide.with(mContext)
                   .load(categoryUrl)
                   .placeholder(R.drawable.two)
                   .into(mCategoryImageView);
       }
   }

   public void setBottomView(String[] optionText, int[] optionResource, int tag) {

       if (mCategoryBottomView != null) {
           CategoryBottomOptions options = new CategoryBottomOptions(mContext, optionText, optionResource, tag, mCategoryBottomView);
       }
   }

   @Override
   protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       super.dispatchDraw(canvas);

       mRect = new RectF(mDivider.getX() - mPadding, mDivider.getY() - mPadding, mDivider.getX() + mPadding, mDivider.getY() + mPadding);
       mPath.addArc(mRect, 270, 180);
       canvas.clipPath(mPath);
       canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

       mRect = new RectF(mDivider.getWidth() - mPadding, mDivider.getY() - mPadding, mDivider.getWidth() + mPadding, mDivider.getY() + mPadding);
       mPath = new Path();
       mPath.addArc(mRect, 90, 180);
       canvas.clipPath(mPath);
       canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
   }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Should do something like this to create a window withing a view.

```
public class ClippedImageView extends ImageView {
    private Paint mPaint;
    private Path mPath;

    public ClippedImageView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
        init();
    }

    public v(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
        init();
    }

    public ClippedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        mPath = new Path();
        RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, 100, 100);
        mPath.addArc(rect, 270, 180);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.clipPath(mPath, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```